# How to get a data under a specific string in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file named `input.txt` .

```
<hello script="2.5">
<welcome>
     <hgsdhjaghjdghjagdjhgjdhgdajhgdajhgdhjjgfkjg
     <number new="0x0000-0x3FF" Id="bhi" Range="4" no_id="hello" />
               
          <----jsdjhsdjndkjjdhjdJHksdkjdnknnddnekfgrejgjorgj jregjgkrjglrjgojggjorjg--->
          <number new="0x02" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000012" no_id="hi all" />
          <number new="0x04" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x0000023f" no_id="dbhwd" />
          <---- dfiuhdwiudi iwqdidffenfj odwqjdjqwgru jdqkkjwfkjfwn odHHOIJD JSDNKS nsk---->
          <number new="0x06" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000f22" no_id="sjkdnkl jdsnj" />
          <number new="0x08" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000f1b" no_id="dm o" />
    <---bdheuh jwdhjwdkiwh---->
</abc>
<abc data="CS"
          <number new="0x32" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000012f5" no_id="he d kd" />
          <number new="0x336" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00000df2" no_id="dnkwn" />
          <number new="0x428" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x0001cbf2" no_id="h nd" />
</abc>
<abc data="CS1">
          <number new="0x35" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000013A5" no_id="lm fed" />
          <number new="0x326" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00003252" no_id="dk bop" />
          <number new="0x466" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00011BF2" no_id="mj ghd" />
</abc>
<abc data="P1">
      <number new="0x06" Id="bhi" Unit="0" unit_id="hi_all" Range="2" info="0x0f22" no_id="sjkdnkl jdsnj' />
       <number new="0x08" Id="bhi" Unit="0" unit_id="this new" Range="4" info="0x00000f1b" no_id="dm o" />
</abc>

<--adhhj jdwjdkkj jsSDjkasdj jefnflefk kjsjfoekfle kajfofkp ksaokdfpef---->
<---the end of file---->
```

From this file i need to create another file named output.txt which will only contain new and info values.

this is my current attempt:

```
import gzip, re
pattern = r'(new=\"\w+\").*(info=\"\w+\")'

with gzip.open("input.txt.gz", "rb") as fin:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            for match_new, match_info in re.findall(pattern, line.decode('utf-8')):
                fout.write(f'{match_new} {match_info}\n')
```

This code produces an output file like this:
`output.txt`

```
new="0x02" info="0x00000012"
new="0x04" info="0x0000023f"
new="0x06" info="0x00000f22"
new="0x08" info="0x00000f1b"
new="0x32" info="0x000012f5"
new="0x336" info="0x00000df2"
new="0x428" info="0x0001cbf2"
new="0x35"  info="0x000013A5"
new="0x326" info="0x00003252"
new="0x466" info="0x0001cbf2"
new="0x06" info="0x0f22"
new="0x08" info="0x00000f1b"
```

However i need only new and info values under **abc data="CS1"**. so my output.txt should look like this:
expected output:
`output.txt`

```
new="0x35"  info="0x000013A5"
new="0x326" info="0x00003252"
new="0x466" info="0x0001cbf2"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: maybe use lxml lib

Comment: Is this supposed to be a valid xml file, but you made a mistake while copying it here, or is it actually something which is almost a valid xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I am going to post this, minus the gzip stuff and minus the nice extraction from the regex.  It uses a basic [State Machine](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/state-machines-python) to decide when to pay attention and when not to.

```
text="""
<hello script="2.5">
<welcome>
     <hgsdhjaghjdghjagdjhgjdhgdajhgdajhgdhjjgfkjg
     <number new="0x0000-0x3FF" Id="bhi" Range="4" no_id="hello" />
               
          <----jsdjhsdjndkjjdhjdJHksdkjdnknnddnekfgrejgjorgj jregjgkrjglrjgojggjorjg--->
          <number new="0x02" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000012" no_id="hi all" />
          <number new="0x04" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x0000023f" no_id="dbhwd" />
          <---- dfiuhdwiudi iwqdidffenfj odwqjdjqwgru jdqkkjwfkjfwn odHHOIJD JSDNKS nsk---->
          <number new="0x06" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000f22" no_id="sjkdnkl jdsnj" />
          <number new="0x08" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000f1b" no_id="dm o" />
    <---bdheuh jwdhjwdkiwh---->
</abc>
<abc data="CS"
          <number new="0x32" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000012f5" no_id="he d kd" />
          <number new="0x336" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00000df2" no_id="dnkwn" />
          <number new="0x428" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x0001cbf2" no_id="h nd" />
</abc>
<abc data="CS1">
          <number new="0x35" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000013A5" no_id="lm fed" />
          <number new="0x326" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00003252" no_id="dk bop" />
          <number new="0x466" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00011BF2" no_id="mj ghd" />
</abc>
<abc data="P1">
      <number new="0x06" Id="bhi" Unit="0" unit_id="hi_all" Range="2" info="0x0f22" no_id="sjkdnkl jdsnj' />
       <number new="0x08" Id="bhi" Unit="0" unit_id="this new" Range="4" info="0x00000f1b" no_id="dm o" />
</abc>

<--adhhj jdwjdkkj jsSDjkasdj jefnflefk kjsjfoekfle kajfofkp ksaokdfpef---->
<---the end of file---->
"""

import re

class WaitState:
    "this is a fairly basic state machine"

    LOOKFOR = {'<abc data="CS1">'}

    marker = None
    pattern = re.compile(r'(new=\"\w+\").*(info=\"\w+\")')
    end = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.found = {}

    def feed(self, line):
        line = line.strip()
        if line in self.LOOKFOR:
            #flip into read mode
            self.__class__ = ReadState
            self.marker = line
            self.found[line] = []
            #marker to show how it ends 
            self.end = line.split()[0].replace("<","</") + ">"

class ReadState(WaitState):
    #read state
    def feed(self, line):
        line = line.strip()
        hit = self.pattern.search(line)
        if hit:
            self.found[self.marker].append(line)
        else:
            if line == self.end:
                self.__class__ = WaitState


reader = WaitState()
for line in text.splitlines():
    reader.feed(line)   

#printing out output - no not necessarily as intended
for k, lines in reader.found.items():
    print(k, ":")
    for line in lines:
        print("  ",line)
```

##### output

(no it's not what you want - I just grabbed the entire line on a hit - but what counts is the state management)

```
<abc data="CS1"> :
   <number new="0x35" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000013A5" no_id="lm fed" />
   <number new="0x326" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00003252" no_id="dk bop" />
   <number new="0x466" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00011BF2" no_id="mj ghd" />
```

p.s.  the `self.__class__ = XXX` stuff works fine for basic state machines in Python.  Bit odd-looking, but as long as your classes are made for this, this works.

This supports more than just 1 type of tag, but it doesn't support nested tags.  That would just be some extra state to look after.

To write the results out to file, again whole-line rather than using regex named groups to isolate `new` and `info`:

```
lines_out = reader.found.get('<abc data="CS1">',[])
with open("output.txt","w") as fo:
    for line in lines_out:
        fo.write(f"{line}\n")
```

which gives:

```
% cat output.txt     
<number new="0x35" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000013A5" no_id="lm fed" />
<number new="0x326" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00003252" no_id="dk bop" />
<number new="0x466" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00011BF2" no_id="mj ghd" />
```

Data structure is  `reader.found : dict[str,list[str]]` .  To get back what you originally had in your desired output just modify the lines

```
if hit: 
    self.found[self.marker].append(line)
```

to extract `new` and `info` from the regex result in `hit`.

Comment: This code works but again i need to use reg ex to get new and info from this output file.

Comment: One problem is that i'm not able to save this output to a file. When i try to write this output to a  file named ```output.txt ``` it is only storing last line of output.

Comment: yes, you can plug in your extraction from the regex  to get info and new.  try using named groups.  no, a general regex.findall wont work - you need to know where you are in the file.  but the comment about `lxml` is valid, use it if you are always on valid xml.  This is more generic to any text format.  i am not familiar with gzip so I don't know how you are only getting one line of text - I would not nest the gzip output writes under the read loop - i'd track my output lines in a list, close the input gzip and then open an output gzip and write lines from my list.

Comment: No actually i used the same code as yours by directly assigning the data to ```text=""" """```. for that i just need the printed output to be written in to ```output.txt``` file. there is no role of gzip there because im not reading any gzip file . still only last line is getting saved to output.txt

Comment: updated with a code sample.