# How to extract specific number of bits from a hexadecimal number for a given text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is input file:
`input.txt`

```
PS name         above bit      below bit      original            1_info           2_info            new      
PS_AS_0         PS_00[31]      PS_00[00]      0x00000000          0x156A17[00]     0x156A17[31]      0x0003F4a1 
PS_RST_D2       PS_03[05]      PS_03[00]      0x00000003          0x1678A1[00]     0x1678A1[05]      0x0a56F001
PS_N_YD_C       PS_03[06]      PS_03[06]      0x00000000          0x1678A1[06]     0x1678A1[06]      0x0a56F001
PS_1_FG         PS_03[31]      PS_03[07]      0x000000FF          0x1678A1[07]     0x1678A1[31]      0x0a56F001
PS_F_23_ASD     PS_04[07]      PS_03[00]      0x00000000          0x18C550[00]     0x18C550[07]      0x00000000
PS_A_0_STR      PS_04[15]      PS_04[08]      0x00000FFF          0x18C550[08]     0x18C550[15]      0x00000000
PS_AD_0         PS_04[31]      PS_04[16]      0x00000000          0x18C550[16]     0x18C550[31]      0x00000000
```

here i need to extract the bits in this way:

if value of `new` =  **0x0a56F001** then first i need that to be converted to binary **0000 1010 0101 0110 1111 0000 0000 0001** .

Then check **above bit** and **below bit** column.

for eg: `PS_03[05]      PS_03[00]`
then take  0 to 5th bit of new binary value which is `000001` which is `0x1` and then convert this to 32 bit value i.e `0x00000001`. and replace **new** column of that row with this value.

```
PS_RST_D2       PS_03[05]      PS_03[00]      0x00000003          0x1678A1[00]     0x1678A1[05]      0x00000001
```

similarly for all and finally the output file should look like this:

```
PS name         above bit      below bit      original            1_info           2_info            new      
PS_AS_0         PS_00[31]      PS_00[00]      0x00000000          0x156A17[00]     0x156A17[31]      0x0003F4a1 
PS_RST_D2       PS_03[05]      PS_03[00]      0x00000003          0x1678A1[00]     0x1678A1[05]      0x00000001
PS_N_YD_C       PS_03[06]      PS_03[06]      0x00000000          0x1678A1[06]     0x1678A1[06]      0x00000000
PS_1_FG         PS_03[31]      PS_03[07]      0x000000FF          0x1678A1[07]     0x1678A1[31]      0x0014ADE0
PS_F_23_ASD     PS_04[07]      PS_03[00]      0x00000000          0x18C550[00]     0x18C550[07]      0x00000000
PS_A_0_STR      PS_04[15]      PS_04[08]      0x00000FFF          0x18C550[08]     0x18C550[15]      0x00000000
PS_AD_0         PS_04[31]      PS_04[16]      0x00000000          0x18C550[16]     0x18C550[31]      0x00000000
```

Is this possible in Python?
This is current attempt:

```
with open("input.txt") as fin:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
         for line in fin:
             if line.strip():
                 line = line.strip("\n' '")
                 cols = l.split(" ")
                 cols[6] = int(cols[6],16)
```

i tried by selecting specific column but it is not working.

Comment: check the above and below column for what?

Comment: to know how many bits to be selected. if it is [05] to [00] then select only that many bits from the binary number and do the rest process.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the "PS_03[05]" format. There are two numbers in this encoding, and since there are two columns with such a pattern, we have four numbers encoded. What do those four numbers mean with respect to a range?

Comment: i need to consider only above bit and below bit column eg for PS_RST_D2  it is "PS_03[05]" "PS_03[00]" . so i need to select 0 to 5 bit binary value of new = 0x0a56F001.

Comment: similarly for next line it is PS_03[06]      PS_03[06] for PS_N_YD_C which means 6th bit of binary value that is 0. then convert to hex 0x0 and finally to 32 bit value that is 0x00000000. and then replace the new value with this value.

Comment: Your expected values are inconsistent. For 00 to 31 you keep **32** bits (including the above bit) while for 00 to 05 you only keep 5 bits (**not** including the above bit). Giving one or the other is not too hard, but you must be consistent...

Comment: @VS: You have not answered my question. If 6 to 6 is the bit 6, then 0 to 5 should be bits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 meaning **6** bits and lead to value `0x00000002`. I have been able to process the input data in my tests, but I have to know the exact specification of the output to post an answer...

Comment: for new = 0x0a56F001 its binary value = 0000 1010 0101 0110 1111 0000 0000 0001. then [05] to [00] mean 0to 5th bit 000001 then convert to hex value = 0x1 then to 32 bit value 0x00000001. for [06] 6th bit is 0. so hec value 0x0. 32 bit value 0x00000000

Comment: If you do not want to read my comments, I cannot help you... **I** have understood that you want bits 00 to 05! But if 0 if first bit, then 5 should be 6th bit. Please answer **that** point.

Comment: Yes. 0 will be the first bit, 5 willl be 6th bit and 6 will be 7th bit and so on..

Comment: You [are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432346/how-to-produce-an-output-file-from-2-input-files-such-a-way-that-output-file-wil) on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385525/how-to-change-a-string-name-in-a-file-when-a-hexadecimal-numbers-is-split) since [at least 2022-11-09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369861/how-to-get-a-data-under-a-specific-string-in-a-file). Maybe you want to take a programming course instead of asking many broad SO questions and producing a lot of spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to split the lines, then a regex to extract the above and below values.

To compute the new value, you can only keep the (above_bit + 1) least signicant bits with a bitwise and with `2**n - 1`, and then right shift the result by below_bit.

Possible code:

```
import re

# compile the regex
bit_re = re.compile(r'.*\[(\d{2})\]')

with open("input.txt") as fin, open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
    line = next(fin)          # skip header line
    fout.write(line)
    for line in fin:
        row = line.split()    # extract fields
        # print(row)          # uncomment for traces
        # extract above and below values
        above = int(bit_re.match(row[1]).group(1))
        below = int(bit_re.match(row[2]).group(1))
        val = int(row[6],16) & (2**(above +1) - 1)
        val = val >> below & (2**(above +1) - 1)
        row[6] = format(val, '#010x')    # format the result as a 32 bits hex number
        print(*row, file=fout)
```

with for sample data it gives as expected:

```
PS name         above bit      below bit      original            1_info           2_info            new      
PS_AS_0 PS_00[31] PS_00[00] 0x00000000 0x156A17[00] 0x156A17[31] 0x0003f4a1
PS_RST_D2 PS_03[05] PS_03[00] 0x00000003 0x1678A1[00] 0x1678A1[05] 0x00000001
PS_N_YD_C PS_03[06] PS_03[06] 0x00000000 0x1678A1[06] 0x1678A1[06] 0x00000000
PS_1_FG PS_03[31] PS_03[07] 0x000000FF 0x1678A1[07] 0x1678A1[31] 0x0014ade0
PS_F_23_ASD PS_04[07] PS_03[00] 0x00000000 0x18C550[00] 0x18C550[07] 0x00000000
PS_A_0_STR PS_04[15] PS_04[08] 0x00000FFF 0x18C550[08] 0x18C550[15] 0x00000000
PS_AD_0 PS_04[31] PS_04[16] 0x00000000 0x18C550[16] 0x18C550[31] 0x00000000
```

You could get a better formatting by replacing the end of `line` with the new value...

Comment: If bit 5 if the 6th bit, it cannot be anything else. That is the reason for all the comments you never directly answered... Said differently, it is always possible to ask for an inconsistent behaviour, but **I** cannot produce a code with non consistent behaviour...

Comment: @V_S: Then `0x0a56F001` starts with `0b00001010...` and not with `0b000001...` (4 bits for the first 0 byte, and then `a` is `1010`).

Comment: extremely sorry for the miscommunication from my side. this is what i meant 0000 1010 0101 0110 1111 0000 00```00 0001```  this will be [05] to [00] then 0x00000001. 0000 1010 0101 0110 1111 0000 0```0```00 0001 this will be [06] to [06] .

Comment: 0000 1010 0101 0110 1111 0000 00```00 0001``` this means 0th bit will be 1 and 5th bit will be 0.  05 to 00 is ```00 0001```.

Comment: Oops, my bad... I was starting from Most Significant Bit while you were starting from Least Significant bit.  Time to have a coffee... Should be soon fixed.

Comment: Thank you.  sorry i should have explained it well.

Comment: @V_S: Please see my edit. I apologise for not understanding the bit order. I think I can now have my coffee...

Answer (score 1):

For reading input-Data like this I like to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/). (update at the end of answer)

To get the number of the above and the below bit, you can use indexing of the string like:

```
sAboveBit ="PS_03[05]"
iAboveBit = int(sAboveBit[-3:-1])
```

Or much safer:

```
iAboveBit = int(sAboveBit.split("[")[-1].split("]")[0])
```

For creating the new value, you could use a bitwise-AND with an integer which you can calculate with your aboveBit and belowBit

first way I think of is a for loop:

```
iSumUp = 0
for i in range(iBelowBit,iAboveBit+1):
    iSumUp+=2**i
```

To getting your number in hex you can use the module/package bitstring.

```
import bitstring as bs
sOldNew = "0x0a56F001"
iOldNew = bs.BitArray(sOldNew).uint
```

Now you can use a bitwise AND

```
iNewNew = iOldNew & iSumUp
```

And finally create your new hex-string with a formatted string.

```
sNewNew = f"0x{iNewNew:08x}"
```

At least save your date to your (new) file, for which I also prefer using pandas.

Update:

For reading your data with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv(r'input.txt',delimiter="\t")
print(df)
```

Comment: yeah but problem is need this to be done using python.

Comment: please check the link. pandas is a module for python

Comment: pandas is not very difficult. you can loop through the dingle columns

Comment: While Pandas is a very nice tool, it is really overkill here... Furthermore it is a rather large module with a lot of dependencies. Fine to use it if it is already there, but I would never install it for such a simple processing...

Comment: Then is there any way i can get output in expected way.

Comment: I'm upvoting, because the OP was not clear on how much data was being passed (maybe the provided data is a snippet). Its a good suggestion, and an intuitive solution for anyone who uses python regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have many spaces. When splitting at the space, you get a lot of empty columns. Replace many spaces with a single one first:

```
import re
line = re.sub(' +', ' ', line)
```

Then, `0x0a56F001` is a hexadecimal number. To read it from the text file, use `int(cols[6], 16)`, not `int(cols[6], 2)`, which attempts to read it as binary.

You can then get a 32 digit binary string like this

```
number = int(cols[6],16)
binary_string = f"{number:032b}"
```

Now do the slicing, then convert it back with

```
sliced_number = int( ..., 2)
```

Comment: but i first need to covert this hex number to binary.

Comment: @V_S: you first need to read the hex number, it's a number then and you can do binary operations on it

Comment: oh okay  i have edited,  thankyou. But is there a way i can get output in the given format.

Comment: @V_S: please don't edit the question in a way that it makes existing answers irrelevant.

Comment: @V_S: The first line of your data contains the column titles. OMG. Do you read the error messages? Do you try to understand them?